# Dialogflow CX Page Fulfillment Response Text Parameter Is List (ES users may know the answer as well)

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

I have a parameter that is defined as a list. When I reference that parameter in the "Agent Says" box, a la the [quick start guide](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/build-agent), I get the list with brackets in the agent response text.

Fulfillment Response Text:
That's a `$session.params.supported_toppings` pizza.

Agent Simulator Response:
That's a [pepperoni] pizza.

I've been all over the documentation for CX and ES, but I can't seem to find any way to unpack the list outside of creating a webhook (which I'm trying to avoid for reasons). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked today the behavior of static responses when referencing parameters and it seems that we can now display the list of values for a certain parameter without the square brackets in the responses.

Here’s the format: ***$session.params.parameter-name*** I’ve used to display the list in the responses. The result of the test is as follows.
[image: CX agent isList]

Moreover, for Dialogflow ES Edition, it is supported. It returns the list of values for a certain parameter using the format ***$parameter-name***. Here’s an example for ES agent:
[image: ES agent isList]

Answer (score 1):

Upon checking the session parameter reference, the format should be as follows: `$session.params.parameter-id[i]` See here for more information: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#session-ref

Here’s an example test done from my end:

1. `isList` Parameter
   [image]
2. Condition for `isList` Parameter
   [image]
3. Test in Dialogflow CX Simulator
   [image]

Based on the screenshots above, the format for referencing `isList` parameters worked.

If you have the an expected number of values for an `isList` parameter, you can use the static response for fulfillment: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#static. You can add multiple responses depending on the parameters to return as seen in the examples provided.

Comment: That's great, assuming you know how long your list is. However, if the list length is dynamic, your solution would require writing n responses where n is the feasible length of the list. I just want to print the entire list without the brackets regardless of length. I have a hard time believing nobody at google has considered that since ES.

Comment: in your answer where you provided two options list[0] or list[0] and list[1] , do you think CX should be intelligent to choose which reply to use based on the number of items in the list? I know ES used to do this when certain entities were set/not set, but I don't think that works for CX. It will just go through the response list and then keep repeating the last item.